# Does long keep Leading zeros SQLITE Insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite, variables, numbers

Simple Question just to confirm.
A method returns a Long, that long may be made up of leading zeros. What are the rules on this. Are the zeros wiped off when it's passed back or do they stay.

Ahh I realised where this gets more complexed
I am currently using this method to add values to a database, it returns a LONG.
[Android SQLiteDatabase.Insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

So I'm wondering if it returns something with a leading zero what's stopping it being chopped off?

Comment: Eh? There are no leading zeros. If you're writing `long a = 00000123;`, you're simply specifying the long in octal (and it's identical to writing `long a = 83;`).

Comment: They're not "wiped off", they were never there.

Comment: To add a different perspective, long and other ints are fixed width internally -- 64 bits internally for long.  So yes, there are always leading zeros if the number takes less than 63 bits to represent it.  (63 because one bit is used for the sign.)

Comment: Please have a look at my orginal edited question

Answer (score 4):

No integral type (or floating point type) preserves leading zeros. In binary, there is no concept of `00` vs `0` (nor in a mathematical sense).

```
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong("001")));
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong("1")));
```

Is just going to display `1` for both.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's because I had something return a single zero '0' and I wasn't sure.

Comment: AHHH here's where I am confused https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: @GideonSassoon returns `long  the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred`. How did that confuse you?

Comment: Frisch, What if the row ID has a leading 0 in it? This worry was given that we count up from 0 here. So the first value which is returned is 0.

Comment: Not necessarily, but there aren't "leading zeros" with a long. More accurately, there almost always are - but the language doesn't display them.